# Where are the systemd configuration Files?

Tags: rhel, systemd

How do I enable particular units in particular targets?  Once enabled, where is the configuration stored?

Answer (score 11):

As Hauke Laging said, `systemctl enable ...` will print out information about what is being done. For instance, on my Arch system, if I enable the `dhcpd` service on interface `enp0s3`...

```
$ systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp0s3
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@enp0s3.service
to /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service
```

When disabling this very service, you can see that `systemctl` removes this previous link...

```
$ systemctl disable dhcpcd@enp0s3
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@enp0s3.service
```

So, from this output, you can tell that...

- When calling `systemctl enable`, a symlink is created under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`.
- When calling `systemctl disable`, this very symlink is removed.

Therefore, if you want to get a list of enabled services (what you're calling "the configuration", I suppose), all you have to do is list these links:

```
ls /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
```

However, you might find more information using `systemctl list-unit-files`, which will list all available services, and their status (enabled, disabled, static). You'll see that the enabled ones have a link somewhere under `/etc/systemd/system`, according to the units they belong to.

```
$ find /etc/systemd/system -type l
```

While the directories may change for some distributions, they are the way `systemd` (and other systems before it) handle their settings. While `/etc/systemd` holds several configuration files, the unit-specific settings are handled through links. To me, this method is a lot more practical than files, since it allows developers to provide units along with their packages (installed under `/usr/lib/systemd/system`), but still gives control to the administrator, who gets to decide which units get to be scheduled on the system.

If you're interested, [the Arch Wiki actually provides a nice introduction to `systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd). RHEL also has [some information about it in their documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html).